# Can an escutcheon be mounted without the valve body plate?

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

The previous owners of the house never had the plumber install the plate on the valve body that the escutcheon would mount to.  Instead they tiled right to the valve body cover:

[image]

The replacement American Standard trim kit has a screw-less escutcheon. Any ideas how how I could mount the escutcheon? The hole for the plate are right on the edge of the tile so i could not drill a hole in the tile

[image]

Comment: is there an adhesive i could use to attach the plastic mounting ring to the tile?  If it didn't hold then i would have messed up tile and no escutcheon to cover it

Answer (score 1):

You could get a pressure sensitive double stick tape to hold it in place while the clear caulk that is used to fix it in place cures.

The tape I refer to has a foam layer in the middle, so multiple layers can be used to hold it in place if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Drill holes through the ceramic tile where the screws are supposed to be. Ceramic tile is much softer than you would imagine when using a tile drill bit, so drilling near the edge shouldn't be a problem. Hold the back plate in place and use a permanent marker to mark the hole locations. Either of the two types of drill bits below will work.

Alternatively, you could use a carbide blade on an oscillating power tool like the Dremel Multi-Max to cut the opening larger.

[image: Tile bit 1]
[image: Tile bit 2]

[image: Carbide blade]